# Why is the prior omitted from this Bayes rule?

Tags: self-study, bayesian, expectation-maximization

I'm trying to understand the EM algorithm. I've found a tutorial on it. It goes like this:

Two coins (A & B). 5 rounds of flipping 10 times. We forgot, however, which coin was flipped each round. What are the probabilities of heads $\theta_A$, $\theta_B$ of the coins?

We map the latent variable (coin used) in variable $Z$ with $p(Z_r=A)=p(Z_r=B)=0.5$. In each round $r$ the number of heads is $x_r$.

$p(X_r = x_r | Z_r=A;\theta)=\theta_A^{x_r}(1-\theta_A)^{10-x_r}$

Now the tutorial says that the posterior using Bayes' rule is:

$p(Z_r = A|x_r;\theta)=\frac{\theta_A^{x_r}(1-\theta_A)^{10-x_r}}{\theta_A^{x_r}(1-\theta_A)^{10-x_r}+\theta_B^{x_r}(1-\theta_B)^{10-x_r}}$

I don't understand why the prior is omitted from the rule here? Shouldn't it be:

$p(Z_r = A|x_r;\theta)=\frac{p(X_r=x_r|Z_r=A;\theta)p(Z_r=A)}{\sum_{C=A,B}\theta_C^{x_r}(1-\theta_C)^{10-x_r}}=\frac{\theta_A^{x_r}(1-\theta_A)^{10-x_r} * 0.5}{\theta_A^{x_r}(1-\theta_A)^{10-x_r}+\theta_B^{x_r}(1-\theta_B)^{10-x_r}}$

Source: http://people.inf.ethz.ch/ganeao/em_tutorial.pdf

Edit: Martijn made things clear for me. For any future readers:

$p(Z_r = A|x_r;\theta)=\frac{p(X_r=x_r|Z_r=A;\theta)p(Z_r=A)}{p(x_r;\theta)}$

\begin{align}
p(x_r;\theta) &= {\sum_{C=A,B}p(x_r|Z_r=C;\theta)p(Z_r=C)} \\ &= p(x_r|Z=A;\theta)p(Z_r=A)+p(x_r|Z_r=B;\theta)p(Z_r=B) \\ &= \theta_A^{x_r}(1-\theta_A)^{10-x_r}*0.5+\theta_B^{x_r}(1-\theta_B)^{10-x_r}*0.5 \\ &= 0.5(\theta_A^{x_r}(1-\theta_A)^{10-x_r}+\theta_B^{x_r}(1-\theta_B)^{10-x_r})
\end{align}

So

$p(Z_r = A|x_r;\theta)=\frac{0.5(\theta_A^{x_r}(1-\theta_A)^{10-x_r})}{0.5(\theta_A^{x_r}(1-\theta_A)^{10-x_r}+\theta_B^{x_r}(1-\theta_B)^{10-x_r})}=\frac{\theta_A^{x_r}(1-\theta_A)^{10-x_r}}{\theta_A^{x_r}(1-\theta_A)^{10-x_r}+\theta_B^{x_r}(1-\theta_B)^{10-x_r}}$

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its [wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: In your sum term you have to add the factor 0.5 as well. $$P(x_r)=\sum_{C=A,B} P(x_r|C)P(C) \neq \sum_{C=A,B} P(x_r|C) $$ (where A,B are disjoint otherwise you need some extra terms)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

$$p(Z_r = A |x_r;\theta) = \frac{p(x_r|Z_r=A;\theta)}{p(x_r\vert\theta)} p(Z_r=A|\theta) $$

Note that $$ p(x_r\vert \theta) = p(x_r|Z_r=A;\theta) p(Z_r = A|\theta) + p(x_r|Z_r=B;\theta) p(Z_r = B|\theta)   $$ 
Eventually those $p(Z_r = A)$  and $p(Z_r = B)$ terms in nominator and denominator will cancel out if $p(Z_r = A)=p(Z_r = B)$, which is why you could not easily spot the prior term.

Comment: Right! after glancing at your answer for a while I understand now. Thanks Martijn :)